# Ajax Update Works in Debug Mode But Not in IIS

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis

I just published a local intranet to the IIS running on my machine. The site is a MVC 4 application. It has the following jQuery code to do an AJAX update of underlying database table and refresh of a web grid showing various database table elements.

```
var printermapping =
            {
                "MTPrinterID": MTPrinterID,
                "NTPrinterID": NTPrinterID,
                "Active": "N"
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/UpdatePrinterMapping/',
            data: JSON.stringify(printermapping),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                gridContent.load('/Home/ #gridContent', function () {
                    showHideButtons(gridContent);
                });
            }
        });


function showHideButtons(grid) {
grid.find('tr.webgrid-row-style, tr.webgrid-alternating-row').each(function () {
    var th = $(this);
    var Active = th.find("#lblActive1").text();
    if (Active == "Y") {
        th.find('.activate').hide();
    } else {
        th.find('.deactivate').hide();
    }
});
```

When I run locally on Debug mode through VSE 2013 for Web, everything works fine. But when I type in a URL to run it from my IIS, showHideButtons work nicely but the AJAX update no longer works. Very puzzled. Can anyone shed some light on what could be the issue? Many thanks.

Comment: I should add that I am running IIS Version 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I did a WinDiff for the page source for both Debug and IIS version. I noticed the following.

Debug version:
form action="/Home/Create" method="post"
IIS version:
form action="/EFRMPRTEST/Home/Create" method="post"
(with some tags removed)

So I modifed my jQuery function by putting in /EFRMPRTEST in front of /Home/ #gridContent in the load function. Now it looks like:

```
var printermapping =
            {
                "MTPrinterID": MTPrinterID,
                "NTPrinterID": NTPrinterID,
                "Active": "Y"
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/UpdatePrinterMapping/',
            data: JSON.stringify(printermapping),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                gridContent.load('/EFRMPRTEST/Home/ #gridContent', function () {
                    showHideButtons(gridContent);
                });
            }
        });
```

Now the IIS version works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue. I was running a web app from within a named website (not the DefaultWebSite). I discovered that my ajax call wanted the path from the web site, not the web app.  I tried the above solution and it worked.  However, I felt I could not be changing the URL each time I moved to a different website on a different server.  So I tried using Url.Action() which worked in my situation. I suspect it would have worked the same for the above user's gridContent.load('Url.Action( '#gridContent', 'Home')', function(){showHideButtons(gridContent);});